How do I get a file's base name from its file path in robotframework?
Suppose I have an arbitrary file path stored in a string variable, such as
Set Variable  ${filePath} = /path/to/a/file.txt

What would be the easiest way to get its name without the extension (file in this particular example)?

I did end up finding a solution, albeit a bit of a verbose one:
${pathComponents} =  Split Path  ${filePath}
${fileName} =  Get From List  ${pathComponents}  -1
${fileBaseName}  ${fileExtension} =  Split Extension  ${fileName}

